# vb.net UDP broadcast show IP from sender

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, sockets, ip

I am sending a UDP broadcast out with the message "Hello?" using this code:

```
    Public Sub UDPSendHello()

    Dim client As New UDPClient()
    Dim ip As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 15000)

    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello?")
    client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ip)
    client.Close()
End Sub
```

Of couse I the UDPListner can recieve the message fine!

```
  Private ReadOnly udp As New UdpClient(15000)
    Public Sub UDPHelloListner()
        udp.BeginReceive(AddressOf Receive, New Object())
    End Sub
    Private Sub Receive(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim ip As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15000)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = udp.EndReceive(ar, ip)
        Dim message As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
        If message = "Hello?" Then
            Dim sender As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15000)
            Dim senderRemote As EndPoint = CType(sender, EndPoint)

            MessageBox.Show("I see message, Hello")
        End If

        UDPHelloListner()
    End Sub
```

Well how can I get the senders IP address and show it in Messagebox,textbox,etc.

I saw the `Socket.RecieveFrom` Method, but! I am getting this error `"The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call"` at this point of the below code, "   `s.ReceiveFrom(msg, SocketFlags.None, senderRemote)`"

```
   Public Sub ReceiveFrom2()
        Dim hostEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())
        Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList(0), 11000)

        Dim s As New Socket(EndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)

        ' Creates an IpEndPoint to capture the identity of the sending host. 
        Dim sender As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
        Dim senderRemote As EndPoint = CType(sender, EndPoint)

        ' Binding is required with ReceiveFrom calls.
        s.Bind(endPoint)

        Dim msg() As Byte = New [Byte](255) {}
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting to receive datagrams from client...")
        ' This call blocks. 
        s.ReceiveFrom(msg, SocketFlags.None, senderRemote)
        s.Close()

    End Sub 'ReceiveFrom2
```

So how would I get the sender IP and show it using the code above in a textbox,message,etc....????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BeginReceive` is an asynchronous call. You need to set up your udp connection before you call `BeginReceive`. I don't know vb.net very well (I use C#), but you need to use something roughly like this:

```
Public Class UdpState
   Public e As IPEndPoint
   Public u As UdpClient
End Class

Public Shared messageReceived As Boolean = False

Public Sub UDPHelloListner()
    Dim ip As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 15000)
    Dim udp As New UdpClient(ip)

    Dim state As New UdpState()
    state.e = ip
    state.u = udp

    udp.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(AddressOf Receive), state)

    Do While Not messageReceived
        Thread.Sleep(100)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Receive(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim udp As UdpClient = CType((CType(ar.AsyncState, UdpState)).u, UdpClient)
    Dim ip As IPEndPoint = CType((CType(ar.AsyncState, UdpState)).e, IPEndPoint)

    Dim bytes As Byte() = udp.EndReceive(ar, ip)
    Dim message As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    If message = "Hello?" Then
        MessageBox.Show("I see message, Hello from {0}", ip.Address.ToString())
        messageReceived = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So how do I convert IP to string? I'm so confused on how I can get the IP of the sender of the UDP broadcast

Comment: Tried a ToString, but doesn't work.    Dim seeIP As String
            ip.ToString(seeIP)

Comment: Sorry, I misread a lot about your original code. You need to send the udp state in the `BeginReceive` call. I've updated my original answer code.

Comment: Yet another edit. I didn't realize that UdpState was not a .NET class. You'll have to forgive my vb.net skills as I use C#, but you need a simple class (`UdpState`) that will hold your udp information. I don't know if the one I wrote is correct, but it should get you in the right direction.

Comment: You are fine! THANKS! You can always write it in C# I use converter.telerik.com/‎ which does a great job of converting.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was use IPEndPoint.ToString Method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.tostring.aspx